# How to create multiple tabbed form subpanels in Flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

There are many tutorials on how to create just tabs in flash but I can't find none which explains how to create associated subpanels and switching between them.

Maybe it's trivial but I'm very novice at flash so I need a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up mx.containers.ViewStack, or mx.containers.TabNavigator.

Basically, you create a bunch of pages as children of ViewStack or TabNavigator, and switch between pages with selectedIndex or selectedChild property. Binding the selectedIndex between the two will automate the switching.

Comment: Oops. Not that it is deprecated, but it's not available in Flash Professional per se. It's part of the Flex framework, I overlooked that you're looking for CS4 solution.

Anyways: This might help - http://jessewarden.com/2005/02/viewstack-in-flash.html